# Digital signature with iText and beID (using 2048 RSA key) on JDK8

Tags: itext, rsa, digital-signature, eid

When used under JKD8, the signature of PDF files using iText and beID (with RSA key 2048 bits) will throws an exception: RSA key must be at most 1024 bits

```
26/09/2014 10:48:36 [exitApplication] [SEVERE] - exitApplication with status 1  
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: RSA key must be at most 1024 bits  
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.checkKeySize(P11Signature.java:363) at sun...  
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Signature.engineInitSign(P11Signature.java::427)

    at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineInitSign (Signature.java:1129)  
    at java.security.Signature.initSign (Signature;java:512)  
    at com.itextpdf.pdf.security.PrivateKeySignature.sign(PrivateKeySignature.java:115)

    at com.itextpdf.pdf.security.MakeSignature.signDetached(MakeSignature.java:152)
```

Comment: What's your PKCS#11 configuration like? This may not be related, but did you install the unlimited strength policy files in your particular Java JRE.

Answer (score 2):

Use an updated version of the middleware that fixes this bug:

[Reported Issue](https://code.google.com/p/eid-mw/issues/detail?id=130)

> This issue should be fixed in the future release build (v410), which you can find on http://eid.belgium.be/en/using_your_eid/installing_the_eid_software/windows/

Comment: This is a valid answer, the answer is to use an updated version of the library that fixes the bug.